# SQL - Query by Date Range

Tags: t-sql, syntax, between

I have an order header table called "OrderH". In this table there is a column called "OrderDate". I am trying to retrieve the orders with a date within a certain range. I thought that I could accomplish this with the "between" keyword but I am not having any luck. This is this SQL I have been fidgiting with:

```
select 
    * 
from
    OrderH h
where
        h.OrderDate between '2009-06-16' and '2009-06-01'
order by
    h.OrderDate desc
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please add more info about which DBMS is that, description of the table in question, error messages if any, etc.

Comment: If MySQL: is your OrderDate a "date" type column or a "timestamp" column?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

the smaller date has to be first

```
between  '2009-06-01' and '2009-06-16'
```

instead of

```
between '2009-06-16' and '2009-06-01'
```

Also be careful when using between because you will get the midnight value from the larger date and nothing else

Take a look at [How Does Between Work With Dates In SQL Server?](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/how-does-between-work-with-dates-in-sql-)

Comment: Wow. I need more coffee. I can't believe I overlooked something so simple.

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to find dates that end before they begin. Change the min and max...

```
h.OrderDate between '2009-06-01' and '2009-06-16'
```

Answer (score 1):

Query does not work because in your example first date is bigger than second date. Swap the dates. First must be less than equal to second date.

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
    * 
from
    OrderH h
where
        h.OrderDate between '2009-06-01' and '2009-06-16'
order by
    h.OrderDate desc
```

Answer (score 0):

In MS-SQL Server events happening after 2009-06-16 at midnight will not be included.